# __doPostBack not working in chrome and safari

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-chrome

__doPostBack() function works in FF and IE,but not working in safari and chrome.
I have following code in my asp.net c# application

ASPX Code

---

```
<a href="www.myAddress.com/abcdef.html" onclick="javascript:SetPosition(); ">Click here</a>
```

JS Function

---

```
function SetPosition() {
        __doPostBack('ahref', 'link');
}
```

CS Code

---

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                // Other code is here
            }
            else if (Request.Params["__EVENTARGUMENT"] != null && Convert.ToString(Request.Params["__EVENTARGUMENT"]).Trim() == "link")
            {
                Session["TopPossition"] = "9999";
            }
}
```

Comment: does your link go through to the page when clicked, or are you preventing the actually link click? e.g. `event.preventDefault();` or `return false;`?

Comment: have you tried using link button or button to test postback ?

Comment: No.I dont prevent link click.when user clicks on link "SetPosition()" gets called and user then redirected to new page(www.myAddress.com/abcdef.html" in this case)

Comment: @Rohit : i don't want to use link button.i want <a> tag

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to pass the server control id as the EventTarget and not the client id when you use __doPostBack call. Try changing the __doPostBack call as so...

```
<a id="someclientid" name="someuniqueid" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="__doPostBack('someuniqueid', '');">val</a>
```

By default, controls use __doPostBack to do the postback to the server. __doPostBack takes the UniqueID of the control (or in HTML, the name property of the HTML element). The second parameter is the name of the command to fire.

Answer (score 0):

The onclick event handler needs to supress the links default behavior to navigate to what's specified in the href attribute.

It should be like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="SetPosition(); return false " >Click here</a>
```

you can provide redirection in SetPosition() if required.